# Responsive Grid Layout Relative to Screen Size

Tags: jquery, css

I have listed my design requirements below -

1. I'm working on creating a responsive grid layout relative to screen size. Similar to the attached image [image]
2. If the user resize the screen, then grids should adjust itself (both in height and width) to occupy the screen size. Technically grids should occupy entire screen without vertical scroll bars.
3. Above condition #2 is applicable only for desktop and tablet devices. For other screen the grid will behave like normal responsive layouts (i.e with vertical scroll bar to display entire content)
4. Can someone please guide me how to implement above requirement using a jQuery plugin or something similar.

Comment: If you won't do it manually, you can use [Bootstrap framework](http://getbootstrap.com/) which its layout system is very easy to use.

Comment: try to use bootstrap. it will help you to complete your task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define width and height in jQuery and also in window.resize
[find fiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/9b7w6507/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="col col30 bgblue"></div>
<div class="col col40 bggold"></div>
<div class="col col30 bgblack"></div>

<div class="col col30 bggreen"></div>
<div class="col col30 bgpink"></div>
<div class="col col40 bgred"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
background:grey;
}
.col{
float:left;
}
.bgred{
background:red;
}
.bggreen{
background:green;
}
.bgpink{
background:pink;
}
.bgblue{
background:blue;
}
.bggold{
background:gold;
}
.bgblack{
background:black;
}
```

jQuery*:

```
function screen(){
var $w = $(window).width()*0.44; 
var $w2 = $(window).width()*0.28; 
var $h = $(window).height()/3; 
$('.col').css({'height': $h +'px'});
$('.col40').css({'width': $w +'px'});
$('.col30').css({'width': $w2 +'px'});
}

screen();
$(window).resize(function(){
 screen();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution looks perfect fit for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have Used Grid Kind of Approach try this, it may Works for you,
For Responsive approach add media queries and than change the column width what you want

```css
* { /*this border-box property will affect IE7 browsers */
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper{
    float: left;
 width: 100%;
}
/*for the box visibily purose only i have added this */
.wrapper  div.inner {
    background: #ccc;
    border: soild 1px #aaa;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.c1, .c2, .c3, .c4, .c5, .c6, .c7, .c8, .c9, .c10, .c11, .c12, .c1-5, .c1-8 {
 min-height: 1px;
 float: left;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 position: relative;
}
.c1 { width: 8.33% }
.c2 { width: 16.66% }
.c3 { width: 25% }
.c4 { width: 33.33% }
.c5 { width: 41.66% }
.c6 { width: 50% }
.c7 { width: 58.33% }
.c8 { width: 66.66% } 
.c9 { width: 75% }
.c10 { width: 83.33% }
.c11 { width: 91.66% }
.c12 { width: 100% }
.c1-5 { width: 20% }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content c8">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar c4">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Three even columns -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content c4">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar c4">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar c4">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```